# Metallic Material Has Black In It

Tags: materials, lighting

If you look on the left rails there is some weird black shading?
(im using blender cycles)
[image: If you look on the left rails there is some weird black shading?]

Comment: Try adding sharps to the ends of the rails (Edge mode, select, right click, sharp) and resetting the normals vectors

Comment: Are you using the Cycles rendering engine?

Comment: It can have multiple reasons. Please share the material node tree

Comment: ...or share blend file

Comment: Yes I am Using The Cycles Engine

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57662/how-to-get-rid-of-shadowy-texture-on-objects

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with *Shade Smooth*.  The normals on the sides are being interpolated to the face on the non-camera-facing side, and so the rendering engine is reporting it as a lost ray because it reflects into the background or otherwise runs out of light bounces before it can find a light.

You can see a recreation of the issue in this example scene.

[image]

Two simple ways to fix:

1. Enable *Auto Smooth* in *Object Data Properties* -> *Normals*.

[image]

[image]

2. Create some supporting loops on the ends to decrease the area over which the interpolation happens.

[image]

[image]